# mvc c# unable to plot flot chart, json data not valid?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, charts, flot

I have controller which takes database data and return json to javascript
But i have problem that i cant show chart but not able to show bars
I tried different methods and now i need your help !

Controller:

```
foreach (Dashboard item in result)
    {
    DateTime kint = Convert.ToDateTime(item.date);
    String dd = kint.Day.ToString();
    stats.Add(new ReferralStat {data = Convert.ToInt16(item.percentage), label = "" + dd + ""});
    perc.Add(new AccupancyPerc {data = Convert.ToInt16(item.percentage), label = Convert.ToInt16(dd)});
    arr.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(Convert.ToInt16(dd), Convert.ToInt16(item.percentage)));
    percent.Add(Convert.ToInt16(item.percentage));
    json_string = json_string + "[" + dd + ", 100], ";
    };
```

I tried to retur diferent formats: stat / perc / arr / percent

```
return Json(stats, "application/json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

JavaScript:

```
function chartWeek(placeholder) {

        var chartdata = [];
        $(function () {
            `$`.getJSON('../../Home/WeekAccupancy', function (chart_data) {
                console.log(chart_data);
                $.plot(placeholder, chart_data, {
                    series: {
                        pie: {
                            show: true,
                            innerRadius: .4,
                            stroke: {
                                width: 4,
                                color: "#F9F9F9"
                            },
                            label: {
                                show: true,
                                radius: 3 / 4,
                                formatter: donutLabelFormatter
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    legend: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    grid: {
                        hoverable: true
                    },
                    colors: ["#7d939a", "#5399D6", "#d7ea2b"],
                })
                //alert(chart_data);   
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: How does console.log(chart_data); look like?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your chart configuration is wrong. You need to put in chart data inside the chart config and it should work hopefully.